# Database update only crashes during runtime but it does not when in debug mode

Tags: android, database, debugging, android-sqlite

I'm working in a project that updates a Database through an `AsyncTask`, when I run it in Debug mode everything goes well, but when I run it in Running Mode, using an AVD, it crashes and give the following message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

As I mentioned before, IT ONLY HAPPENS THAT CRASH IN RUNNING MODE WITH AN AVD!!!

Can anyone explain me what is going on?

After Karan Dhillon' suggestions:

I've already tried both ways using Executors (with FixedThreadPool) and using HandlerThread, because I need to insert several new rows in a database, and I even changed the method to insert these data, using ContentValues and SQL Query through a String. All the way, I still got the following error message when in Running mode through AVD: When I try to insert with SQL Query:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Worker Process: com.jagetram.senarand, PID: 6006 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: TABLE_NAME.FIRST_FIELD (code 1299) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)

And when I try to insert with ContentValues:

E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "null": syntax error E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (null) VALUES (NULL) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of the `string` variable being passed below:

```
void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)
```

Procedures happening in the `DEBUG` mode should not be taken as final. `Runtime Procedures` are more reliable as they are being executed in real environment and how your end users will use the application.

On a side note, `AsyncTask` is `@Deprecated` and should be avoided whenever possible.

If you are using `JAVA` then try `Executors` or `Handlers`. 
If you are using `KOTLIN` then try `Coroutines`.
You can use `RxJava` for both of them, but it comes with its own complexities.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Karan! I"ll look on how to change my code to RxJava. I hope this is not too difficult!!

Comment: I would personally suggest to look at Executors and handlers or coroutines based on your choice of language, rather than learning RxJava, because RxJava tends to have a bit of a learning curve.